# Firebase Twitter Authentication and PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, web, firebase

So guys, i'm making an app using the PhoneGap technology and i find myself in an issue: I'm using Firebase to authenticate from twitter, the problem is when i press the button "Sign in with Twitter"  it don't open the popup like in the computer so it just don't do nothing, here's my code

```
function Login(type)
{
    var count = 0;
    var fire = new Firebase("https://olimpo.firebaseio.com");
    fire.child('users').once('value', function(data){count = data.numChildren;});
    var auth = new FirebaseAuthClient(fire, function(error, user){
        if (error)
        {
            ShowMessage(error);
        }
        else if (user)
        {
            var usr = new Firebase("https://olimpo.firebaseio.com/users/twitter/"+user.id);
            usr.once('value', function(data){
                if (data.numChildren() > 0)
                {
                    usr.set({last_loggin: Date()});     
                }
                else
                {   
                    usr.set({name: user.displayName, username: user.username, timestamp: Date(), last_login: Date(), email: "none", password: "none"});
                }
                sessionStorage.setItem('user_id', user.id);
                sessionStorage.setItem('user_provider', type);
            });

            loadDashboard();
        }
    });
    if (self.location.href.split("#")[1] != "dashboard")
    {
        var remember = false;
        if ($("#saveSwitch").val() == "on")
        {
            remember = true;
        }
        auth.login('twitter', remember);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Engineer at Firebase here. Firebase Simple Login does not currently support PhoneGap out of the box for pop-up based authentication methods due to its locally-hosted nature and non-standard behavior with respect to pop-up windows. However, this is something we are actively working on and hope to have fully-supported within a few weeks. I'll follow-up here as soon as we've made progress on this issue. Thanks!

**Update:**

Firebase has recently released a number of updates adding full support for Adobe PhoneGap / Apache Cordova, including fully supporting Firebase Simple Login for Facebook, Twitter, GitHub, and email / password authentication methods.

Check out the blog post at https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-16-firebase-adds-phonegap-cordova-support.html for more info!

Comment: Is there better documentation on this? I'm not sure if I'm using the auth script properly. It redirects me to Twitter login, but it seems to hanging on the callback page.

Comment: @dmackerman In general, Firebase Simple Login should behave the same on PhoneGap as on the desktop as long as you have the InAppBrowser / ChildBrowser module included. There's a PhoneGap-specific example posted at [https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login-phonegap](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login-phonegap) that you can check out as well.